# Нужен совет по разработке приложения для Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

Хочу на дипломный проект разработать приложение под Android, ибо под Delphi уже все мозги  закоптили, ВУЗах только так и делают, мол используйте Delphi и т.д, хочется что-нибудь новое сделать). Будет называться "Помощник менеджера",
Суть такова:

Менеджеры которые ходят по магазинам и предлагают товары, приложение будет иметь список категорий и товаров. Вот заказали 200 пачек масла, менеджер заходит

> "Продукты -> Молочные - Масло -> и тут
>   список производителей"

, он дальше сам выбирает кого и сколько, потом данные идут на сервер и с общей БД снимается то кол-во товара, которое он выбрал. Дальше сделаю форму добавления товаров и управления на сайте, в виде пары страничек (редактирование/добавление) товаров.

Вопрос:

> -Нужны ли очень хорошие знания в программировании под Android (я просто
>   недавно начал изучать, но сам думаю
>   что смогу сделать).
>
> -Какую связку посоветуете что-бы приложение могло:    а) если в
>   настройках выбран пункт "Только
>   Онлайн" тогда приложение при каждом
>   выводе списка товаров и добавлении
>   будет делать запросы на сервер ,
>   который будет на MySql и PhP для
>   добавление товаров.
>
> б) выбран "Оффлайн" приложение
>   будет работать с текущей БД а при
>   нажатии кнопки "Обновить данные БД"
>   будут переданы в БД которая на
>   сервере, (этот пункт если менеджер 1)
>
> -Возможно ли сделать взаимодействие приложения на Android с базой MySql на
>   сайте.

P.S если нужно, буду использовать другую БД , например SQlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нет
2. JSON, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpClient,
3. Да, но через сервис (PHP). Можно наверное собрать через NDK MySQL клиента, но овчинка выделки не стоит

Comment: А можно по подробнее про "сервис PHP"?

Comment: http://devcolibri.com/1486

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)